# Debugger agent is not enabled : ionic 2 app with visual studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, debugging, ionic2

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Apache Cordova for developing Ionic 2 + TypeScript Application on window 10. I have an app who works. But when I debug (Debug > Android > Ripple), the debug output window does not display debug messages. Instead, I get the following message:

'
code:-32000 message:Debugger agent is not enabled The source map 'es6-shim.map' for file 'C:...\www\build\js\es6-shim.min.js' could not be read from the specified location due to error 'Exception of type 'TypeScriptSourceMapReader.SourceMapReadFailedException' was thrown.'.

My tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "!node_modules/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

My project : [Img Projet](http://postimg.org/image/7zxxs5ggx/)

How to solve this Error?